# Stress test mqtt broker (HiveMQ CE broker)

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, load-testing

I have to stress test (load test) an MQTT broker on my machine (or a machine in my network) for getting say the number of clients that can simultaneously remain connected to the broker on that machine, the number of messages that can be simultaneously published by different clients to registered topics and things like these.
How can I achieve this?

I'm quite new at this and have seen some videos about Jmeter but where can I get answers to the questions mentioned above in Jmeter? Just a side note, Jmeter doesn't have inbuilt MQTT support and people have made some plugins for this, namely, https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter

p.s. Jmeter is not a necessity. I just mentioned it because I found some videos and resources on it.

Comment: There are many ways you could stress test a broker (build a lab running multiple instances of your apps or use tools such as jmeter, [Gatling](https://github.com/mnogu/gatling-mqtt), [mqtt-malaria](https://github.com/etactica/mqtt-malaria) etc). However unless the test simulates your real world work loads (e.g. number of connected clients, QOS, message size/volume/timings, number of subscriptions, encrypted vs unencrypted connections etc) I'm not sure that the test will achieve much. Note than questions asking for tool recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

1. [MQTT Connect](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter#connect-sampler) sampler opens a connection (one connection per JMeter thread - virtual user) so if you have 2 threads defined in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - 2 connections will be open.
2. [MQTT Pub Sampler](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter#pub-sampler) sends message to the defined topic over the existing connection. If you want to send messages to different topics from the same user - you can parameterize the topic names using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), the same applies to the message payload
3. When you're done you can call [MQTT DisConnect](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter#disconnect-sampler)

See [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide) article for more detailed information if needed.